# How to detect for a particular target "logo" in an image, when it can be distorted?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, detection, object-detection

Suppose I have all these commercial products' logo (they are just images) in my database, and I take photos of these logo in the real world, how can I make it so that my program can detect such logo in my photos? The constrains are:

For example, a soccer player could be wearing a shirt that has Coca-Cola logo and his shirt has wrinkles all over, which distorted the logo. Here is an example of how it might look like. On the left is the original, and the right is the distorted version:

[image: logo test C]

Another example is I take a photo of a street straight ahead, and in the photo, there is a McDonald sign on the sidewalk and from the photo's perspective, this McDonald logo on the sidewalk may look like the 'M' on the right, while the 'M' on the left is the original image:

[image: logo test M]

So given these constraints, the logos may look distorted in any way in real world, yet of course, if the logo in the photo is distorted to the point that we can't figure, then that is out of scope. But if there is an original "scent" of the logo, then it should be possible, no?

How can I detect the logo in the photo in this case? What are some of the algorithms or methods I should be looking for?

Comment: More suitable to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a machine learning task. Get some examples image of the logo in as much distorted views as possible. Then train some object detector to find the logo for you.

Things you might want to consider

- You will need a lot of training data to do this. You might want to generate synthetic (mirrored) distortions to get enough training data
- The literature on object detection is rich with many different algorithms. There is not solution that will work right out of the box. Try out several algorithms, I'd start with a bag of words, or SVM
- You will probably have to do a 'sliding window' detection style to find the logo in the image. Think of the logo as a 2D pattern that you want to detect in a bunch of data

Good luck!